# Could not find job with ID in AppEngine Datastore Admin (entity delete operation)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to **delete an entity type in the datastore** from the Datastore Admin console in appengine. After I started the delete operation, I clicked on the job link to check the status, but it's showing:

```
Error -- KeyError: "Could not find job with ID u'158795848290450'"
```

The entity type has not been deleted and the status of the operation is:

```
Active (0 steps completed, 1 active)
```

For the past 24hrs I've tried different entity types, but nothing is getting deleted.
**Is this a bug in appengine or is it application specific?**

Please guys help me to solve this issue? I've been stuck on this for more than 2 days...

Comment: Have you tried simply re-running the delete operation?

Comment: @Nick johnson thanks for reply .i found the issue.Default queue is paused,so it blocked the job.The error message from delete job was not clear.Still some of old jobs in active status thats not changing the status to complete.The new jobs working fine.Is there any possibility that the old tasks get triggered in future,because site going live in couple of days..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Nick Johnson the failed jobs are still in active status(check task.jpg file in this post [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-python/lPaqXfHuATw/ybQF662hSz8J)), will the failed tasks get triggered and delete the entity in future?

Comment: Check the task queue in the admin console. If there aren't any tasks, there's nothing to run. You can also delete the status entities from the datastore.

Comment: Some clarification on how to delete the status entities: You should see a kind called '_AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation' in the Datastore Viewer. You can delete the stuck operations from there. (@Nick Johnson Perhaps you want to create an answer? Didn't want to steal your thunder..)